# Windows 11 DNS Blackholing Domains - How to remove Tailscale

Tags: windows

I was reviewing the technology of tailscale for my home and work use..   And it still has some interest had to table project for a while.

I uninstalled the tailscale client from Windows 11 x65 23H2 and started seeing weird DNS issue.

I spent several weeks running down ratholes assuming it was other issues

https://www.elevenforum.com/t/windows-dns-subdomain-blackhole.19082/

Turns out.. Tailscale did not uninstall correctly and now my system is having major issues.

Question

1. How to I get windows back to normal DNS and DNS services?
2. Why did an uninstall of tailscale go so badly?

To install tailscale client.   But when uninstall selected. the OS is put back to standards where the UI effects DNS and DNS is not left orphaned

Comment: this was resolved via posting on GItHub.   https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/9948